# Need to create code in asp.net mvc 5 solution to receive and send json strings server to server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, http

I have recently returned to .net programming after a 7 year break.

I need to learn how to write a project within an existing open source asp.net mvc 5 ecommerce solution to receive posted json strings from a remote server running php with cURL, send acknowledgement responses, create my own json strings to post back to the remote server and receive acknowledgement responses. This must all be done with server side code, with no client side component whatsoever.

Serializing and deserializing json is not the issue, its using the correct kind of pages or services to send and receive json on the server without any client component, and using http objects directly. I have no experience or knowledge of creating this kind of project.

This is my question: I have had a look at a couple of tutorials about using .ashx and httpClient and httpContext but found them a little confusing. I would like to find a comprehensive guide about how to use json to communicate server to server with realistic examples. Is there one available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a perfect use case for WebApi. It is made specifically to work with JSON (or XML) requests and should work fine with requests issued by other scripts (not browsers).

There are plenty of tutorials available. Here is the [official introduction tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api).

Comment: Thanks. Once I have read some documentation, I will mark this as the right answer if .net web api turns out to be the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

What I often do to create JSON in C# is make an object/class which I serialize to JSON.
My controller has an function:

```
public JsonResult FunctionName()
{
    var json = new { x1 = 10, y1 = "Hello" };
    return Json(json);
}
```

You can call that function with PHP.